# How to simulate file picker step in Cypress in order to check the remaining steps

Tags: angular, cypress

I'm having troubles with testing file upload scenario in Cypress in Angular app.
These are the steps:

1. User picks a file, clicks 'Select' and modal pop up with a form opens.
2. User fills out the form and clicks ok.
3. File is uploaded and the form values are sent to the server.

Cypress doesn't support a file picker. But i need to test the other steps user makes when a file was picked. How in Cypress I can trigger a function that opens a pop up if in the app this function is triggered by file input change event? Maybe it's possible to trigger the function right in the test (similar to unit tests, i.e. component.setSelectedFiles() ) and bypass file picker at all?

App.component.html

```
<label class="btn" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
  Upload
  <input type="file" multiple (change)="setSelectedFiles($event.target.files)"> 

</label>
```

App.component.ts

```
setSelectedFiles(fileArray) { // This function is triggered when user selects a file
  this.files = fileArray
  this.showModal = true    // this step opens a modal pop up.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed quite a bit in a [Cypress issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/170).  The answer with a lot of up votes is this one below, I'm doing something similar in our tests.  If that doesn't work, take a read through that issue and there will probably be a workaround that will work for you.

```
cy.fixture('path/to/image.png').as('logo')
  .get('input[type=file]').then(function(el) {
    return Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob(this.logo, 'image/png')
      .then(blob => {
        el[0].files[0] = blob
        el[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true}))
      })
  })
```